How do I add text over my grid of images?
I am just starting out with basic web design, and I am struggling to find a way to put my text over the images in a grid for the different services offered. Sorry for the messy code.
I also added an image of a rough mockup of the website look I am trying to achieve.
Mockup Website
The code I am working with:
body, h1, h2, h3, p, ul, li, img {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
   
}

header {
    background-color: #1a1616;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 1px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 20pt;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
p {
    font-size: 20pt;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 150px;

}

nav ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Oxygen", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    
}

.cta-button {
    background-color: #c72d41;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 50px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Oxygen", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    margin: 5%;
}

#about {
    position: relative; /* Ensures absolute positioning inside */
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

#about img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    z-index: -1; /* Ensure the image is behind text */
}

.about-overlay {
    position: relative; /* Required for z-index to work */
    z-index: 1; /* Ensure the text is above the image */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* semi-transparent black overlay */
    padding: 150px;
    font-family: "Oxygen", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
}

}
    
.case-container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat (5, 20%);
        grid-template-rows: repeat (5, 20%);
        column-gap: 10px;
    }

    #case-1 { 
        grid-column: 1 / 4;
        grid-row: 1 / 6;
    }

    #case-2 { 
        grid-column: 4 / 6;
        grid-row: 1 / 3;
    }

    #case-3 { 
        grid-column: 4 / 6;
        grid-row: 3 / 6;
    }

    #caption-1 {
        grid-column: 1 / 4;
        grid-row: 1 / 6;
    }

    #caption-2 { 
        grid-column: 4 / 6;
        grid-row: 1 / 3;
    }

    #caption-3 { 
        grid-column: 4 / 6;
        grid-row: 3 / 6;
    }

.centered {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 10;
    font-family: "Oxygen", sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

#services {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    padding: 100px 0;
    text-align: center;
        font-family: "Oxygen", sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
      
}
    .image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    }
    
    .text {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    }

.grid-container { z-index: -1; ;display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); /* Three columns */ grid-gap: 0px; } .grid-item { /* Style for each grid item */ } /* Adjust grid items if needed */ .grid-item img { max-width: 100%; /* Ensure images don't exceed their container */ height: auto; /* Maintain aspect ratio */ }

.grid-item img {
  width: 100%; /* Make image fill the container width */
  height: auto; /* Adjust height automatically to maintain aspect ratio */
}

.grid-item {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 10, 0.8);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
  }

#services ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#services ul li {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

footer {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.social-links {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: "Oxygen", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}

.social-links li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.social-links li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>rimberiobarbershop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oxygen:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
        
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <img src="Images/Logo/rimberio_transparent_logo.png" alt="rimberio logo" style="width:200px;height:200px;">
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <a href="#book-now" class="cta-button">Book Now</a>
</header>

<section id="about">
    <div class="about-overlay">
        <h2></h2>
        <p>Precision Meets Elegance - Every Detail Counts.</p>
        <img src="backgroundplaceholder.jpg" alt="Man Receiving Haircut">
    </div>
</section>

</body>
</html>


<div class="grid-container">
  <!-- First Row -->
  <div class="grid-item"><img src="Images/haircuts.png" alt="Image 1"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><img src="Images/haircolor.png" alt="Image 2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><img src="Images/eyebrowshape.png" alt="Image 3"></div>
  
  <!-- Second Row -->
  <div class="grid-item"><img src="Images/facialtreatments.png" alt="Image 4"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><img src="Images/straightrazorshave.png" alt="Image 5"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><img src="Images/waxing.png" alt="Image 6"></div>

  
</div>

</html>

<footer>

    <ul class="social-links">
        <li><a href="#">Hours of Operation:</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="social-links">
        <li><a href="#">Monday - Friday 8:00 am - 5:00 pm</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="social-links">
        <li><a href="#">Saturday - Sunday 8:00 am - 12:00 pm</a></li>
    </ul>
        
    <ul class="social-links">
        <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
    </ul>

</footer>
</html>

I tried searching for specific code but the changes I want don't seem to be happening.
